How does photon exchange create an attractive force? (electromagnetism)
excuse my classical way of thinking, but how is it that electromagnetism (or any other fundamental force that is mediated by particules) can be an attractive force, yet work by exchanging photons, and as far as I know, when you throw something, even at an atom's scale, well, you get accelerated in the opposite direction of the thing you thrown, you don't suddendly go in the direction as what you thrown, so how is it that those forces seemingly do just that? electromagnetism seemingly is about charged particles throwing balls at each others, and it makes them attract each others, or did I miss something?
so while I may brush this question away when my brother ask me and I answer him it's like they play toss and they become friends, but for some reason I doubt that's how it works
(finally my turn to ask a question here after using this website for so long)

Linked.
